# Did Pre-Shankara scholars of other darshanas consider Vedanta to be Advaita only?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, shad-darshana, darshan

Shri Sacchidananda Sarawati in his Introduction to the [Brahma Sutra Bhashya Kannada translation](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.363055/page/n16/mode/1up), Part 1, page 14, which says,

[image]

Translation

> 3. As in Vedanta other Darshanas are taken up for refuting them, when other Darshanas take up Vedanta for refuting it, the others always
>    consider Vedanta to be Advaita.

This a claim Swamiji is making to prove that Vedanta was considered as Advaita itself even before Shri Adi Shankaracharya.

**My question is which are those Pre-Shankara books available today, which considers Vedanta to be Advaita? What did they say about Advaita?**

Comment: Who is downvoting and why? Do you understand it? Exaplin it. Blind downvoting is bad.

Comment: I think The kannada is speaking about contemporary darshanas

Comment: @KrsnaDasa no if you read the whole page it will become clear. He is talking about Pre-Shankara time.

Comment: Then one can consider Ashtavakra and Gaudapada as pre Shankara advaitians.

Comment: @KrsnaDasa yes ofcourse. The question is not whether Advaita was present before Adi Shankara or not. The question is whether other forms of Vedanta were present Pre-Shankara.

Comment: If one considers Ashtavakra Gita and Gaudapada Karika as advaita vedanta works.

Comment: @KrsnaDasa yess but are there works of Bhedabheda, Vishistadvaita and Dvaita?? Are such schools mentioned by Jains, Buddhists, Yoga-Sankhyas, Nyaya-Vaisheshikas and Purvamimamsakas??? That is the question

Comment: Vishistadvita considers, Bhagavadbodhayana
2. Tanka
3. Dramida
4. Guhadeva
5. Kapardi
6. Bharuchi as pre Shankara,Vishishtadvaita commentators on Brahma Sutras.

Comment: @KrsnaDasa yes this is what I'm asking. Are their works available? If not were they spoken by people of other Darshanas?

Comment: Madhvacharya also mentions 1.Bharativijaya
2. Samvidaananda
3. Brahmaghosha
4. Shataananda
5. Vaagbhatta
6. Vijaya
7. Rudra Bhatta
8. Vamana 9.Bhartrprapanca 10.Vijaya Bhatta
11. Visnukranta
12. Vaadindra
13. Madhavadesaka as pre Shankara commentators on Brahma Sutra. He says there are whom all he is going to refute in his commentary. Their works may be mentioned here and there by different commentators. Another pre Shanka commentator is VishnuSwami (shuddha advaita) and his bhashya is called Sarvajna Sukta, Sridhara Swami quotes from this work in his Bhagavatam commentary.

Comment: @KrsnaDasa yes but none of those works are available now afaik. So we can't verify it. That js why I'm asking people who are not Vedantis, what have they spoken about Vedanta? People like Jains, Buddhists, Yoga-Sankhyas, Nyaya-Vaisheshikas and Purvamimamsakas

Answer (score 1):

There are fourteen purely Shaivite Upanishads, plus the Shvetashvatara Upanishad. All of them are not at all in the spirit of Shankaracharya's Advaita-Vedanta:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaiva_Upanishads

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shvetashvatara_Upanishad

And the four Vedic Samhitas and the Brahmanas adjacent to them are essentially the philosophy of Purva-Mimansa, and not Vedanta-Darshana at all:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C4%ABm%C4%81%E1%B9%83s%C4%81

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakha

Comment: That is not my question

Comment: Most of the Upanishads, Puranas and Itihasas are written in the spirit of Advaita Vedanta. They already existed before the birth of Shankaracharya. The problem only arises with certain Upanishads, clearly Shaivite, clearly Vaishnavism and clearly Shakta. There is also a problem with the Brahma Sutras, because Bhaskaracharya's commentaries, according to scholars, reflect the essence of these sutras more accurately and much better than Shankaracharya's commentaries. Bhaskaracharya was a Vaishnava (Bheda-Abheda). And the problem with the Vedic Samhitas, I already said why.

Answer (score 0):

All the four vedas actually and equally say about Advaita , Vishishta advaita and dwaidha. To be honest, pre shankara time faced many anti vedic practices due to misinterpretation of vedas (no much scholars were there to guidefor some time) . It was shankaracharya who gave the advaidic interpretation of vedas. I can't suggest any upanishad to say that vedant is advaidic because, vedas are the three (advaita, vishishta advaita and dvaita together). But you can take anything at a time from the veda. All the books gave explanation of all the 3 but it was shankaracharya who explained the advaita portion alone to my knowledge

Comment: I'm asking about people of other Darshanas talking about Vedanta

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).